# Matlab HDF5 and JHDF5 library mismatch crash?

Tags: java, matlab, hdf5

I'm using Matlab version R2013b on Linux Ubuntu 12.04 and have a Matlab application that depends on the [Java HDF5](http://www.hdfgroup.org/products/java/) the one from [HDFGROUP](http://www.hdfgroup.org/). My problem is that the JHDF5 wrapper composed of the two files `jhdf5.jar` and `libjhdf5.so` seems to be in some form incompatible with the HDF5 library integrated within Matlab.

My environment is setup as follows i.e. to ensure a version of JAVA within Matlab:

```
$ env | grep JAVA
MATLAB_JAVA=/opt/dev/java/1.7.0_55/jre
JAVA_HOME=/opt/dev/java/1.7.0_55
JAVA_VERSION=1.7.0_55
```

I start Matlab from a directory where I set the following two files to setup the JHDF5 library:

**java.opts**

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xmx4091m
-Xms2048m
-Dncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib=/opt/dev/jhdf5/2.7/lib/linux/libjhdf5.so
```

**javaclasspath.txt**

```
/opt/dev/jhdf5/2.7/lib/jhdf5.jar
...
```

From within Matlab I get the following (meaning I have HDF5 version 1.8.6 and all the rest i.e. JRE and JHDF5 setup as required):

```
>> [maj,min,relnum] = H5.get_libversion
maj =
     1
min =
     8
relnum =
     6

>> java.lang.System.getProperty('ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5.hdf5lib')
ans =
/opt/dev/jhdf5/2.7/lib/linux/libjhdf5.so

>> version -java
ans =
Java 1.7.0_55-b13 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

but then when I try to run a simple command e.g. create an instance of `ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5` or simply access it from the Matlab command line, Matlab crashes

```
>> ncsa.hdf.hdf5lib.H5 % crashes Matlab
```

I some times see the following error popping out in the console:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.8.6) thread 0:
    #000: H5Edeprec.c line 186 in H5Eget_minor(): not a error message ID
    major: Invalid arguments to routine
    minor: Inappropriate type
```

To recap I have the following versions:

- Java JDK 1.7.0_55
- Matlab R2013b
- HDF5 native library version 1.8.6
- JHDF5 wrapper library version 2.7 that is compatible with HDF5 native 1.8.6. See the compatibility note here [RELEASE.txt](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/prev-releases/HDF-JAVA/HDF-JAVA-2.7/RELEASE.txt)